# Duration of an increasing annuity

Tags: calculus, summation, finance

I am having the problem computing the duration of an increasing annuity. I know that the annuity is payable for 20 years, the first payment is $24,000$ and each next payment is $1,200$ larger than the previous one. The interest rate is 5%.

So, I know that the the expression for duration is:
\begin{equation}
\text{duration} = \sum\frac{ t x_t v^t}{x_t v^t}
\end{equation} 
Computing the expression in the denominator is easy. What is more difficult is the expression in the nominator, since we get there:
\begin{equation}
duration = \frac{24000  (Ia)_{20} + \sum_{n=1}^{20}n(n-1)1200v^n}{24000(a)_{20} + 1200\frac{(a)_{20} - 20v^{20}}{i}}
\end{equation}
So the problematic expression is the sum in the nominator. Of course I could simply compute each value by hand and sum it up but I think that there is a smarter way to do it. I wouldn't have any problem for computing this if it was an infinite annuity, since then I could just plug these expressions:
\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^2x^n = \frac{x(x+1)}{(1-x)^3}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}nx^n = \frac{x}{(1-x)^2}
\end{equation}
However, I cannot come up with the analogous expressions for finite sums.
Any help will be appriciated!

Comment: Did you mean ${\rm duration}=\frac{\sum_t tx_tv^t}{\sum_tx_tv^t}$?

Answer (score 1):

You should find that in any extended formula collection.
\begin{align}
(1-x)\sum_{n=1}^N nx^n
&=\sum_{n=1}^N nx^n-\sum_{n=2}^{N+1} (n-1)x^{n}\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^N (n-(n-1))x^n + (1-1)x^1-Nx^{N+1}\\
&=x\frac{1-x^{N}}{1-x}-Nx^{N+1}
\end{align}

Similarly for the quadratic coefficients you find
\begin{align}
(1-x)^2\sum_{n=1}^N n^2x^n
&=\sum_{n=1}^N n^2x^n-2\sum_{n=1}^N n^2x^{n+1}+\sum_{n=1}^N n^2x^{n+2}\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^N n^2x^n-2\sum_{n=2}^{N+1} (n-1)^2x^{n}+\sum_{n=3}^{N+2} (n-2)^2x^{n}\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{N+1}(3)x^n-(N+1)^2x^{N+1}+N^2x^{N+2}-x\\
&=3x\frac{1-x^{N+1}}{1-x}-(N+1)^2x^{N+1}+N^2x^{N+2}-x
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

I don´t know why do  you want to calculate the  duration. In the exercise it is given. You can calculate the present value of all payments. The formula is

$PV=a\cdot \frac{q^n-1}{i\cdot q^n}+\frac{d}i\cdot \left(\frac{q^n-1}{i\cdot q^n}-n\cdot q^{-n} \right)$

with $q=1+i$, $n:$=years of payments, $i:$=interest rate, $d:$=increasing value of the payments per year

The formula cannot be solved for n. The present value in your exercise is

$PV=24,000\cdot \frac{1.05^{20}-1}{0.05\cdot 1.05^{20}}+\frac{1200}{0.05}\cdot \left(\frac{1.05^{20}-1}{0.05\cdot 1.05^{20}}-20\cdot 1.05^{-20} \right)=417,279.14$

---

For $n=3$ it can be tested if the formula works.

$PV=\frac{24000}{1.05}+\frac{25200}{1.05^2}+\frac{26400}{1.05^3}=68519.6$

Using the formula

$PV=24000\cdot \frac{1.05^{3}-1}{0.05\cdot  1.05^{3}}+\frac{1200}{0.05}\cdot \left(\frac{1.05^{3}-1}{0.05\cdot  1.05^{3}}-3\cdot  1.05^{-3} \right)=68519.6$

Comment: But I need to calculate the duration - that's the point of the exercise, what do you mean by saying that it's given? As I said, I know how to calculate the present value of payments, the sum in the nominator is the tricky part.

Comment: @Julia  Quote:What do you mean by saying that it's given?" Quote:"I know that the annuity is payable for 20 years.." But maybe I´ve understood something wrong.

Comment: Now I understand what you meant :) In annuities, duration is a term for annuity's sensitivy with regard to changes of interest rates and one can compute it with the formula given above. It doesn't mean how long annuity lasts.

Comment: @Julia So you solve $PV=a\cdot \frac{q^n-1}{i\cdot q^n}+\frac{d}i\cdot \left(\frac{q^n-1}{i\cdot q^n}-n\cdot q^{-n} \right)$ for $a(i)$ and then calculate $a'(i)$ ?